# Forcing SSL across all pages of a site

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I purchased `EV Certificates` for my websites and I'm attempting to force HTTPS whenever a user types in:

- mycoolwebsite.com
- www.mycoolwebsite.com
- http://mycoolwebsite.com
- http://www.mycoolwebsite.com

Currently I have this code in my `htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

However, it does not seem to be working properly. It only forces SSL on my homepage and no other pages on the site.

I did a bit of research and found this block of code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm wondering are these doing the same thing?

Comment: Do you possibly have any other rules defined before this one, which end in an `[L]`...?

Comment: @deceze not directly before it but further up the htaccess file I have this: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Well, there you go. Those rules are processed first and stop all other rules from being evaluated.

Comment: But if that's the case then why does it force https on the homepage?

Comment: Because that doesn't match those other rules for whatever reason. Either way, you want the basics like HTTP to HTTPS redirects to be handled ***first*** before looking into the other details of the request. So place that rule first.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules are evaluated in the order they're written.

```
RewriteRule A B
RewriteRule C D
RewriteRule E F
```

For every single incoming HTTP request, this will first rewrite `A` to `B`, then `C` to `D`, then `E` to `F`.

If any rule ends with `[L]` ("Last"), that means all following rules shall be ignored if the `[L]` rules matches.

In your case, you have some such rules which are checked first and which apply, so your HTTPS redirect is not evaluated.

Put such fundamental rules first. For every incoming HTTP request, you want to start by asking *"Are we speaking the correct protocol?"* and fix that if necessary, before going on to check more in-depth rules and do internal rewrites.